# Getting console logged messages from code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to know if there exists any way to retrieve messages logged in the console during runtime, from code. I'm deploying an app on Android and as far as I know, console can only be printed under development builds while I want it under *stable release*.

Comment: If it's Android, they may be in the logcat output.

Comment: `Debug.logger.logEnabled = true;` & try use android monitor?

Comment: I think [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/125049/is-there-any-way-to-view-the-console-in-a-build.html) unity answer post might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a class and add a callback method with the [`LogCallback`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.LogCallback.html) signature to [`Application.logMessageReceived`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-logMessageReceived.html) and/or [`Application.logMessageReceivedThreaded`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-logMessageReceivedThreaded.html)

And initialize the class using the [`[RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute.html)

For example for collecting all log outputs during runtime

```
public static class DebugListener
{
    public static List<LogEntry> logs = new List<LogEntry>();

    [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]
    private static void InitializeOnLoad()
    {
        // removing the callback first makes sure it is only added once
        Application.logMessageReceived -= HandleLog;
        Application.logMessageReceived += HandleLog;
    }

    private static void HandleLog(string logString, string stackTrace, LogType type)
    {
        logs.Add(new LogEntry(logString, stackTrace, type));
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class LogEntry
{
    public string Message;
    public string StackTrace;
    public LogType Type;

    // default constructor is required for serialization
    public LogEntry() { }

    public LogEntry(string message, string stackTrace, LogType type)
    {
        Message = message;
        StackTrace = stackTrace;
        Type = type;
    }
}
```

instead of only collecting them in a list in `HandleLog` you can ofcourse also use the received log data otherwise like e.g. adding it to a [`UI.Text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Text.html) component etc

---

Alternatively the simplest solution to directly display the text is also to use the methods from before but in a MonoBehaviour component and display the text using [`OnGUI`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnGUI.html) and [`GUI.Label`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Label.html)

```
public class DebugListener : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string lastMessage;
    private string lastStackTrace;
    private LogType lastType;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        Application.logMessageReceived += HandleLog;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        Application.logMessageReceived -= HandleLog;
    }

    private void HandleLog(string message, string stack, LogType type)
    {
        lastMessage = message;
        lastStackTrace = stack;
        lastType = type;
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastMessage)) return;

        // show text at certain offset from left top corner
        // and certain size
        // e.g. simply place it in the center of the screen 
        // and make it overlay the entire screen
        GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width / 2f, Screen.height / 2f, Screen.width, Screen.height), $"{lastType}\n{lastMessage}\n{lastStackTrace}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, your answer is very complete. I will give it a try or I might end up using an emulator.

Comment: How does it work with OnEnable() and OnDisable()? I thought those methods execute only when the script is enabled or disabled (from the object the script is attached to being enabled and disabled).